# Unobtrusive validation editorfor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, unobtrusive-validation

I've got a partial `View`, loaded from an `Action`, so the parent view contains:

```
@Html.Action("TourSearch")
```

The TourSearch View uses a editor as such:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImpersonatedAgentModel, "ImpersonatedAgentView")
```

where `ImpersonatedAgentModel` is as such:

```
[Serializable]
  public class ImpersonatedAgentModel
  {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a User ref")]
    public string AgentImpersonatedUserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please provide a ABTA/AgencyCode")]
    public string AgentImpersonatedBranchCode { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide a User ref")]
    public int? AgentImpersonatedBranchID { get; set; }
  }
```

My editor is pretty straight forward:

```
@model Travel2.WebUI.Models.ImpersonatedAgentModel

<ul id="agencyDetails">
    <li>
        <label for="AgentImpersonatedBranchCode">ABTA/Agency Code: *</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AgentImpersonatedBranchCode, new {ID="txtBranchCode" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentImpersonatedBranchCode, "*")
        <input id="txtBranchId", type="hidden" value="@Model.AgentImpersonatedBranchID" />
        <input id="txtUserName", type="hidden" value="@Model.AgentImpersonatedUserName" />
        <input id="hidCurrentController" type="hidden" value='@ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue' />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="AgentImpersonatedUserName">User ref: *</label>
        <select id="ddlUser" disabled="disabled" ></select>
                <input type="hidden" id="txtUserID" />
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AgentImpersonatedUserName, new {ID="AgentImpersonatedUserName" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AgentImpersonatedBranchID, new {ID="AgentImpersonatedBranchID"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AgentImpersonatedUserName, "*")

    </li>

</ul>
```

Now in Chrome, all works fine. But when I fill in the form in **IE** but not the data in the Editor, **it passes validation incorrectly**!

If I examine the markup, using IEs poor excuse for Firebug, I can see the validation attributes,

```
<input name="ImpersonatedAgentModel.AgentImpersonatedBranchCode" id="txtBranchCode" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please provide a ABTA/AgencyCode" jQuery172048066185567747205="94"/>
```

so why is IE ignoring them!! Stupid IE

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: IE 9. Not compatibility mode

Comment: Do you have two editors cause the full editor code uses TextBoxFor

Comment: Just to be clear: the client side or the server validation is not working? Have you checked that the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` is referenced in your view and loaded correctly?

Comment: It's client side and server side, but I'm more concerned with the client side tbh. Yes, the js files are all loaded correctly. I've also just updated them to the latest version using NuGet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here:

http://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/26/jquery-validate-and-microsofts-unobtrusive-validation-dont-play-well-together/

We were referencing Jquery validation too and this seems to be causing this error